# Solve cauchy problem $y'=1+y^2, p(\pi)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve cauchy problem $y'=1+y^2, p(\pi)=1$

I tried to do it in traditional way and my answer was:
$y=tg t+C,  C=1$ but it isn't correct.

Comment: Separate the variables.

Comment: I did it that way and my solution was $tg t+ tg \frac{\pi}{4}$ but the answer should be $tg (t- \frac{3}{4} \pi )$

Comment: I didn't realise $tg$ was meant to be $\tan$. You should get $y(t)=\tan(t+C)$, not $y(t)=\tan t +C$. Read the answer below. The solution given differs from that of the answer due to $\tan$ being periodic.

Comment: What is $p$?{}{}

Answer (score 3):

We have $$\frac{dy}{dx} =1+y^2$$ hence $$\frac{dy}{y^2 +1} =dx$$ integrting both sides we obtain $$\arctan y =x+C$$ hence $$y=\tan(x+C).$$ Substituting $x=\pi ,y=1$ we obtain $$\tan (C+\pi ) =1$$ hence $$C=\frac{\pi}{4} +k\pi$$ and the solution is $$y=\tan\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right) .$$

Comment: I up voted, but there's something wrong. It doesn't follow that $C=\frac \pi 4$ as suggested by 'hence'. That's simply one possibility that works.

Comment: I edit. The constant may be equal to $C=\frac{\pi}{4} +k\pi $ but $$\tan\left( x+\frac{\pi}{4} +k\pi \right) =\tan\left( x+\frac{\pi}{4}  \right)$$

Comment: Now I oppose to 'the solution is':P I'd rather say 'a solution is'.

Comment: Yes you're right. I've just corected this.